# I'm trying to do a voting system using Prolog

Tags: prolog

My code:

```
voterid(X):- (X>=18), write("Candidate is eligible for casting a vote").
voterid(X):- (X=<18), write("Candidate is not eligible for casting a vote").
```

My query:

I want to check the nationality of the voter - must be American to be eligible.

How do I do it?

Comment: `voterid(X):- (X>=18)` the name `voterid` suggests that it tests if the voter's ID is greater than 18, rather than testing if their age is greater than 18; is that correct? Do you have a database of voters to work with?

Comment: I'd recommend https://www.reddit.com/r/prolog/ instead, for such a simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose X is not just only the age, but the profile of a person.
It would be a predicate with some atoms, in your case an atom for the age and another one for the nationality.

You could have:

```
voterid(person(Age, american)) :- 
    Age >= 18,
    write("Candidate is eligible for casting a vote").
```

If you want to accept people from certain nationalities, you can adapt the code as follows:

```
nationality(american).
nationality(anotherone).

voterid(person(Age, Nationality)) :-
    Age >= 18,
    nationality(Nationality),
    write("Candidate is eligible for casting a vote").
```

Comment: Would put `american` as the *first* argument, to (at least potentially) take advantage of first-argument indexing. "voterid" should probably have its meaning changed to e.g. `voter_eligible`